# How to prevent Eclipse CDT/GDB from breaking on signals (select system call)?

Tags: gdb, eclipse-cdt

Eclipse CDT is constantly breaking in **select** system call. And this makes debugging very difficult - another process depends on timeout. At the beginning Eclipse has shown "Can't find a source file" dialog:

> Can't find a source file at "/build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/misc/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux        /select.c" Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.

In preferences I switched option "Show source not found editor" to "Never" - it stoped opening editor but continue to break. How to stop breaking in such places (in files that do not belong to project)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of **signal** received by program and it's possible to skip break. It stops not because of absent source file, in my case - absent file is coincident only and only because of absent file debugger will not stop.
In Debugger console I noticed following:

```
Program received signal SIG34, Real-time event 34.
0x00007ffff78f2ff7 in __GI___select (nfds=7,  at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/select.c:41      in ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/select.c
```

This break is because of signal. Documentation says that it's possible to skip breaking on signals using handle command. I used following gdb command:

```
(gdb) handle SIG34 nostop
```

Now program is not interrupted (there is notice in console about each signal).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your .gdbinit

```
handle SIG34 nostop noprint
```